# Rails activeadmin custom view and assotiations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, activeadmin

I've bound the activeadmin gem to `Order`, a model.

I would now like to customise the detail view in activeadmin for this model to show a list of items associated with that order. (like `orders.line_items.each do`...)

Where could I make such a customisation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a thorough walkthrough of the gem's features here at 
[tuts+](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/create-beautiful-administration-interfaces-with-active-admin/)